# browser adds strange characters instead of html

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, textedit

I'm using textedit in a mac and in all browsers: Safari, Firefox and Chrome. I am getting strange characters instead of quotation marks. My browsers are set to UTF encoding and my textedit is in plain text mode.

Comment: Please provide more information: What are the characters you get? Where do you get them in the browser or in 'view page source' or when you use 'inspect element' ?

Comment: In both. It's also obvious when I try to go to a link and it will show up as an broken link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you save the file as UTF-8:
TextEdit > Preferences… > Open and Save, and making sure the Save As setting is "Unicode (UTF-8)"

Also specify the characterset in the html page by adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

between the  tags.